# Get rid of doubled lines in tcbraster

Tags: tcolorbox

When I tex the following, the lines have different heights (double the size if between two boxes)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fitting,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

The brown Fox jumps

\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  boxsep=0pt,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
  fit algorithm=hybrid*,raster equal skip=0mm}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster rows=4,width=75mm]
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,height=8mm]
  \tcboxfit{Test1}  
  \tcboxfit{Test1}  
  \tcboxfit{Test1}  
\end{tcbraster}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,height=8mm]
  \tcboxfit{Test1}  
  \tcboxfit{Test1}  
  \tcboxfit{Test1}  
\end{tcbraster}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

I did not find the parameter to use to make all lines the same height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `raster equal skip` to a negative value:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fitting,raster]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}\
\tcbset{colframe=black,colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  boxsep=0pt,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
  fit algorithm=hybrid*,raster equal skip=-0.5mm,}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster rows=4,width=75mm]
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,height=8mm]
  \tcboxfit{Test1}
  \tcboxfit{Test1}
  \tcboxfit{Test1}
\end{tcbraster}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,height=8mm]
  \tcboxfit{Test1}
  \tcboxfit{Test1}
  \tcboxfit{Test1}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have running text above the table, that now will be half overwritten by the boxes. Any idea?

Comment: Insert some space, e.g. with \medskip. Or with `raster before skip=1mm` in the first inner raster.

Comment: just being curious: the -0.5mm? is this a guess or a derived value from the other values?

Comment: It's the default width of frame rules. You have two rules here side by side and I'm putting them on top of each other.